# Excel - Change hyperlinks

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, hyperlink

I have a bunch of pictures names hyperlinked to picture locations. So if a user clicks the picture name it opens the picture.  I need to send this excel file to clients and I do not know where there pictures are stored.  I would like to create a cell that has a path to the pictures that the client can change and have it either change all the hyperlink paths when that cell changes or when you click on the picture have it add the path to the filename. Is this possible?

Comment: Are your picture links in Excel? If so, how have the links been created? With Insert > Link or with the worksheet function Hyperlink()? Please **edit your question** to provide more detail.

Comment: I can do it either way

Answer (score 1):

Use a cell to enter the path to the folder where all the pictures live. This cell can be in a special sheet that is used for setting parameters like that. I often have a sheet called "Setup" in my workbooks for that purpose.

For ease of use, give the path cell on the Setup sheet a range name, let's say "PicturePath". Make sure the cell contains a valid path to a location.

Let's say on another sheet you have a list of file names in column A. You can then use something like this to create a hyperlink to a file:

```
=HYPERLINK(PicturePath&A1,A1)
```

[image]

If the files are in a different location, just change the path in the one cell.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at some macros I have created for this purpose.
set the path in the macro then highlight all the cells you want to link and run the macro. There is also a revers to turn the formulas back to filenames.

See: [EXCEL HYPERLINK: Link JPG in folder via hyperlink](https://superuser.com/questions/1193499/excel-hyperlink-link-jpg-in-folder-via-hyperlink/1290997#1290997)

[image]